# It won't hurt you doing Vs. It won't hurt for you to do

Tags: word-choice

> It won't hurt you doing it.
>
> It won't hurt for you to do it.

What's the nuance between those? Is it just a matter of formality?

Comment: grammatical is: Doing it won't hurt you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first appears odd. I don't think that this is the form that is usually used.

The second example, and that given in a comment "Doing it won't hurt you." Seem very similar. They both would give an for a rhetorical effect, a form of exaggeration or hyperbole:

> It won't hurt to get up on time(!)
>   It won't hurt for you to get up on time(!)
>   Getting up on time won't hurt(!)